# Pandas transformation of a column to row in a .rolling() fashion

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, rolling-computation

Imagine I have the following Series:

```
inp = pd.Series(np.arange(10))
```

What I want to do, is to transform it to a `np.array` in the following way:

| input | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | NaN | NaN | NaN | Nan | 0 |
| 1 | NaN | NaN | NaN | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | NaN | NaN | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | NaN | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 6 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |

...and so forth.
The column called input is not expected in the output, but I placed it here to make my inquiry more clear.

What I tried is the following:

```
matrix = [x.to_numpy() for x in list(inp.rolling(window=5, min_periods=5))]
```

Problem is, i can't use `np.stack()` on `matrix`, as (even though I passed `min_periods=5`) the shape of every item in the list is different.
Also I feel like I am overlooking a very simple pandas command :D.

Thank you very much!

EDIT:
My current workaround is a custom function. I guess there are way better solutions than this one:

```
def rolling_transform_series(x):
    length = len(x)
    array = []
    for idx in range(length): 
        s = x[idx-5:idx]
        if idx < 5:
            s = np.r_[np.zeros(5-idx), x[:idx]]
            s[s==0] = np.nan
        array.append(s)
    return np.array(array)

df = inp.apply(rolling_transform_series)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with shift:

```
import pandas as pd
inp = pd.Series(np.arange(10))
pd.DataFrame([inp.shift(s) for s in range(4,-6,-1)])

     0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0
2  NaN  NaN  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0
3  NaN  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0
4  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0
5  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0  NaN
6  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0  NaN  NaN
7  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
8  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
9  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Unfortunately that is not really working in my case, if I understand correctly. My dataset has roughly 8 million datapoints and i can't do the full transform and cut it afterwards. But I will tinker around with .shift() a bit more! Thank you Andreas